# Where to download trial of SharePoint Standard 2013?

Tags: 2013, download

I need SharePoint to check some integration capabilities.

At http://sharepoint.microsoft.com there is a big button labeled `Download SharePoint trial`.
**But** clicking on it redirects me to http://www.microsoft.com/office/preview/en/office-365-enterprise , where I am tricked into signing up for a SaaS productivity suite.

Where to download a trial of SharePoint Standard 2013?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sharepoint 2013 trial seems to be available for download here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/evalcenter/evaluate-sharepoint-server-2013

Comment: @lovethakker: As written at the top of the answer, unfortunately Microsoft broke that URL earlier this year :-/

Comment: you can download image file from link - https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/evalcenter/evaluate-sharepoint-server-2013

Comment: @lovethakker: Thanks a lot! I updated the answer.